# how to filter rows that satisfy a regular expression via pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nlp

I'm trying to figure out a way to to select only the rows that satisfy my regular expression via Pandas. My actual dataset, data.csv, has one column(the heading is not labeled) and millions of row. The first four rows look like:

```
5;4Z13H;;L
5;346;4567;;O
5;342;4563;;P
5;3LPH14;4567;;O
```

and I wrote the following regular expression

```
([1-9][A-Z](.*?);|[A-Z][A-Z](.*?);|[A-Z][1-9](.*?);)
```

which would identify `4Z13H;` from row 1 and `3LPH14;` from row 4. Basically I would like pandas to filter my data and select rows 1 and 4. 
So my desired output would be

```
5;4Z13H;;L
5;3LPH14;4567;;O
```

I would then like to save the subset of filter rows into a new csv, filteredData.csv. So far I only have this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import re


sys.stdout=open("filteredData.csv","w")

def Process(filename, chunksize):
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
        df[0] = df[0].re.compile(r"([1-9][A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z]|[A-Z][1-9])(.*?);")
        sys.stdout.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Process('data.csv', 10 ** 4)
```

I'm still relatively new to python so the code above has some syntax issues(I'm still trying to figure out how to use pandas chunksize). However the main issue is filtering the rows by the regular expression. I'd greatly appreciate anyone's advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to read the csv as pandas dataframe and then use str.contains to create a mask column

```
df['mask'] = df[0].str.contains('(\d+[A-Z]+\d+)') #0 is the column name
df = (df[df['mask'] == True]).drop('mask', axis = 1)
```

You get the desired dataframe, if you wish, you can reset index using df = df.reset_index()

```
    0
0   5;4Z13H;;L
3   5;3LPH14;4567;;O
```

Second is to first read the csv and create an edit file with only the filtered rows and then read the filtered csv to create the dataframe

```
with open('filteredData.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    with open('filteredData_edit.csv', 'w') as f_outfile:
        f_out = csv.writer(f_outfile)
        for line in f_in:
            line = line.strip()
            row = []
            if bool(re.search("(\d+[A-Z]+\d+)", line)):
                row.append(line)
                f_out.writerow(row)
df = pd.read_csv('filteredData_edit.csv', header = None)
```

You get

```
    0
0   5;4Z13H;;L
1   5;3LPH14;4567;;O
```

From my experience, I would prefer the second method as it would be more efficient to filter out the undesired rows before creating the dataframe.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, how could I do this while preserving the other data contained in the rows? So instead of having `0   4Z13` and `3   3LPH14` I'm trying to get `5;4Z13H;;L` and `5;3LPH14;4567;;O`

Comment: This is great and pointed me in the right direction. For others, you can just store the booleans in their own variable, separate from the `df`. In other words `mask = df[0].str...` and then `df = df[mask]`. Then you aren't adding a column just to filter by it and remove it.